# Adding different colors to linear-gradient using SASS

Tags: css, sass

How can i get this CSS output (given below) using SASS? because i don't wanna write this long code.

```
 input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    hsl(0, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(10, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(20, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(30, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(40, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(50, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(60, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(70, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(80, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(90, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(100, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(110, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(120, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(130, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(140, 100%, 50%),
    ...
    ...
    hsl(360, 100%, 50%)
  );
}
```

Comment: use CSS to SCSS converter

Comment: since it's a gradient you only need `linear-gradient(
    to right,
    hsl(0, 100%, 50%),
    hsl(360, 100%, 50%)
  );` this is the purpose of gradient

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually i'm creating a color picker app and i wanna show all the different colors, your solution won't work because it would show only two colors

Comment: my solution will show a gradient between tow colors exactly the same as your code. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf8g7zwh/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok try 0 to 170 and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **@for loop** to help you with that case.

You create an empty string.
Then you fill that string by concatenating one line at a time. *hsl(x, 100%, 50%),*
Then you use that variable in your rule.

```
$colors : '';

@for $i from 0 through 36 {
  @if ($i == 36) {
    $colors : $colors + 'hsl(' + 10 * $i + ', 100%, 50%)' // Don't add the ',' if $i == 36, the last item
  }
  @else {
    $colors : $colors + 'hsl(' + 10 * $i + ', 100%, 50%),'
  }
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(
  to right, 
  #{$colors}
  );
}
```